# cmake error find_package cmake_modules

Tags: python, ros-melodic, catkin, ros-kinetic, find-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some time in the last 24 hours (2019.10.27), the ROS apt repositories started publishing the following:

- python-catkin-pkg-modules (0.4.14-1)
- python-catkin-pkg (0.4.14-100)

Right around that time, fully *all* of my `CMakeLists.txt` started producing errors of the following form:

```
CMake Error at /home/luser/copy_catkin_ws/src/foobar/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package) Failed << robot_models:cmake [ Exited with code 1 ]
: By not providing "Findcmake_modules.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "cmake_modules", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cmake_modules" with any of the following names:

cmake_modulesConfig.cmake
cmake_modules-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "cmake_modules" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "cmake_modules_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "cmake_modules" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the manner by which I'm invoking `find_package(catkin)` and/or `find_package(cmake_modules)`. Here's what was working right up until yesterday:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(foobar)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)
catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  INCLUDE_DIRS inc
)
...
```

Here's what the associated `package.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>foobar</name>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <description>The FooBar Thinger</description>
  <author email="author@foobar.com">author person</author>
  <maintainer email="maintainer@foobar.com">maintainer person</maintainer>
  <license>GPL</license>
  <url type="website">http://foobar.com</url>
  <url type="repository">https://github.com/foobar/foobar</url>
  <build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
</package>
```

Anybody know what happened on 2019.10.26 regarding `python-catkin-pkg-modules` and `python-catkin-pkg`? I'm willing to believe I was laboring all along with broken `CMakeLists.txt` and/or `package.xml`, but I would like to understand what happened.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336266/cmake-error-find_package-cmake_modules/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2019-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, this one is on me. Until recently, in my build environment, just after I ran `rosdep` against the `package.xml`s in my source space and just before I ran `$ catkin config --install && catkin build`, I did a `# apt purge --yes sudo`. This ~is~ was fine, so long as `sudo` was never an (eventual) build-time dependency. On 2019.10.26, that all changed and, for the first time, removing `sudo` from the set of installed packages caused `ros-cmake-modules` to be removed along with it. I've since stopped twiddling packages between the invocation of `rosdep` and the build proper.

---

Originally posted by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) with karma: 193 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The updated `python-catkin-pkg[-modules]` packages have nothing to do with the above error message.

The error message indicates that you either don't have `ros-<distro>-cmake-modules` installed or haven't sourced `/opt/ros/<distro>/setup.<shell>`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-11-04**:
@dirk-thomas, you're absolutely correct; thank you for your reply. I've amended my original question with an update explaining my particular situation, how that contributed to the problem, and how I've addressed it. Sorry for the distraction.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-05**:
@rubicks: as helpful as @Dirk Thomas' comment is, it's not the answer.

Your edit is the answer, as that explains what caused your problems.

My suggestion would be to post your edit as an answer and accept your own answer. That would clearly show what the cause was and how you fixed things.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-11-05**:
@gvdhoorn , done and done; thanks for the help.